# From list create new one list with explicity values from first

Tags: python, list

I have some api request and as response I got json which I put in list.
That list is :

```
[
   {
      "status": "running",
      "node": "node-name",
      "uptime": 9484726,
      "name": "hostname",
      "maxcpu": 2,
      ....
      ....
      ....
      ....
   },
   {
      "status": "running",
      "node": "node-name",
      "uptime": 9484726,
      "name": "hostname",
      "maxcpu": 2,
      ....
      ....
      ....
      ....
   },
   {
      "status": "running",
      "node": "node-name",
      "uptime": 9484726,
      "name": "hostname",
      "maxcpu": 2,
      ....
      ....
      ....
      ....
```

From this list I need to create new one which have only name and vmid, and need looks like:

```
[
   { 
     "name": "some-name",
     "vmid": "some-vmid"
   },
   { "name": "some-name",
     "vmid": "some-vmid"
   }
```

How to do this in Python ?

Comment: Why dont you use pandas's Dataframe for your problem.

Comment: `map(lambda d: {'name': d['name'], 'vmid': d['vmid']}, mylist)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this list comprehension like this,

```
result = [{'name':i['name'],'vmid':i['vmid']} for i in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
small_list = []
for dic in big_list:
    small_list.append({'name': dic['name'], 'vmid': dic['vmid']})
```

Comment: Yea, GREAT ! I try something like this, but I make error. Thank you everyone on answer !

Answer (score 0):

pandas is an open source library providing high-performance, easy-to-use data structures and data analysis tools for the Python programming language. For more information please refer this [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/).
Code using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(input_list)
list_dict = data[["name", "vmid"]].to_dict(orient="records")
```

or you can we create dataframe using JSON itself read_json

```
data = pd.read_json(json_data, orient="records")
list_dict = data[["name", "vmid"]].to_dict(orient="records")
```